# How To a Data Post With HttpUrlConnection?

Tags: android, json, post, httpurlconnection

I have got a ajax code you can see below;

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.whoisxmlapi.com/whoisserver/WhoisService',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    type:'POST',
    data: {
        domainName: 'domaindomanin.com',
        outputFormat: 'json'
    },
    success: function(data) {
    }
});
```

First how can i do this in android-java ?

is it normal json data post and read ? if it is how can i do it with HttpUrlConnection class ? I was use before HttpClient but now its obsolate because of my current sdk.

Comment: I recommend using volley or retrofit. Do not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @drulabs can you give me a tip for using wheel ?

Comment: it is available all over, just google it out. here is one https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-http-client-get-post-download-upload-multipart-request.html

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
InputStream executePostRequest(HttpURLConnection conn, Request request) 
{
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        String requestString = request.generateBody();
        byte[] outputInBytes = requestString.getBytes("UTF-8");

        OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        out.write(outputInBytes);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        request.setRequestStatus(conn.getResponseCode());

        try {
            return new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException err) {
            return new BufferedInputStream(conn.getErrorStream());
        }
    }
}
```